# Why does the video cut out on HX-100 drone?

Tags: video-transmitters

I have a BetaFPV HX-100 drone which I recently got. When I tried to fly it FPV the video feed would cut out and leave a grey screen. The OSD still showed up in the goggles so I'm not sure if there is a problem with the camera or video transmitter.

The VTX was hot to the touch and the camera was warm. It was not the output power setting of the VTX because it cuts out even at a close distance to my goggles. I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this issue.

This happens when flying normally or even hovering and the grey screen is a solid grey, not static. I have not had any big crashes with it.

[image: Grey screen from HX-100]

Comment: Some more information would be useful - are you doing and manoeuvres when the video cuts out? The grey screen - is it a flat colour, or is there static present? Also, have you had any hard crashes lately?

Comment: This happens when just flying normally, no excessive amp draw or anything. I have not crashed it lately and the grey color is a flat color with no static present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a loose video wire from your camera to your flight controller.  Since you still see OSD, but a gray screen, it indicates that the connection from the flight controller to the VTX is good (that's why you are seeing OSD), but the gray indicates that something is wrong on the camera end.

A warm camera is a little alarming.  A warm VTX is normal.

I would check all of your connections to your camera.  If they all seem fine, then the problem could be the camera (the warm camera seems culprit to me).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will check connections and if the problem persists, I have a spare camera I can try.

Comment: Some cameras are also getting warm. I would consider that normal too.

Answer (score 2):

From the information you have provided, I think you have a loose connection between your camera and your FC.

My troubleshooting methodology is:

We know that the VTX is functioning as there is no static.

We know that the signal from your FC to your VTX is not being interrupted as the OSD is still transmitted.

This leads me to believe that your VTX is transmitting the data it is receiving, which is not video.

[This](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2672611-Grey-screen-in-goggles) forum suggests that your camera might not be getting sufficient power, so I would check your power cable to your camera.

Comment: Thanks, I will check all of the connections and make sure everything is connected properly.

Comment: @JacobB apparently I missed the part that you still see OSD - in this case I reckon it’s a loose connection between cam and FC

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on a quad: perfect image on the bench but the picture from the camera went bad as soon the quad was in the air.

The error was that the sma connector of the vtx did touch the carbon of the frame. When I isolated the SMA connector (tape + plastic screws to mount it) the problem was completely gone.

Might be a different problem in your case since you are using a prebuilt quad but try to check if the antenna touches the carbon. Maybe some motor screws touch the windings of the motor or some other parts touch the carbon frame.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen at or below a certain voltage? I have the HX115HD, and my video freezes almost exactly @ 11v on 3S. I contacted support, and they have changed the HX115 over to use a Caddx Baby Turtle instead of the RunCam Split 3 Nano because of this issue. I'm waiting on a replacement camera from BetaFPV now.

Comment: This happens even with a fresh charge so I don't think it is related to the battery.

Comment: Barring a loose connection - contact BetaFPV support. You might have a day or so lag, but they've been generally helpful.